# JSON string decode

Tags: xcode, json

I receive a JSON object as :

Pots veure bé les anotacions que tenen accents? O caràcters "estranys"? Tipus l'ampersand &, les cometes ", les u's amb dièresis ü, apòstrofs ' i coses així?","numAnotacions"

when really is :

Pots veure bé les anotacions que tenen accents? O caràcters "estranys"? Tipus l'ampersand &, les cometes ", les u's amb dièresis ü, apòstrofs ' i coses així?","numAnotacions"

So, I don´t find the way to decode the string. I get the string :

NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

Please anyone can help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I thing [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) can help with parsing JSON ([example](http://www.14oranges.com/2011/08/how-to-use-jsonkit-for-ios-and-the-rotten-tomatoes-api/)).

Comment: I'm sorry but when I paste the original response in the above form then appears correctly. Really I receive :  Pots veure b&eacute; les anotacions que tenen accents? O car&agrave;cters &quot;estranys&quot;? Tipus l&#39;ampersand &amp;, les cometes &quot;, les u&#39;s amb di&egrave;resis &uuml;, ap&ograve;strofs &#39; i coses aix&iacute;?","numAnotacions"